# Title custom blocks

Tags: macros, spacing, bibtex

how can I make the custom blocks for my title section inside the `.tex` file? I mean except `\author` `\date`. For example I need the UDC (universal decimal code) numbers right before the title of my article. How can I make it? (I know I can write the class, but may I not do this?)

Code snippet:

```
\documentclass[14pt,letterpaper]{article} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel} 
\usepackage{hyphenat} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
... 
\title {\textbf{The article title}} 
\author[]{Author 1.} 
\author[]{name} 
\affil[*]{company name} 
\affil[2]{university} 
\date{}
```

Comment: #title #custom_title #class #.tex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you know environment `tittlepage`?

Comment: @Mensch of course, but I don't answer about thesis title page...I need the title with abstract and introduction sections together. Using the title page is more easier I think

Comment: Actually I have tried multiple .tex files with title and abstract fillings and showing text with \input{title_page}
\input{Abstract}

Comment: But this doesn't work properly

Comment: Can you please show us a short TeX code building your title page and abstract? Without personal informations, please. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ....

Comment: Ah, of course, I use standard template for article and libraries in .tex file like this: \documentclass[14pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
... \title {\textbf{The article title}}


\author[*]{Author 1.}
\author[*]{name}

\affil[*]{company name}
\affil[2]{university}

\date{} So I need more specific information as I noted before

Comment: @Mensch what will be your advice?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I got how to do it...I am writing the new class and \newcommand inside it with fields for what I need as UDC, DOI, etc. I just wished somebody knows how to make custom title with additional block without classes just in one .tex file...